# Using Regex on Express with MongoDB

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb

I want to use regex to find records that match certain pattern on Express.js using MongoDB.

Here is my code

```
var urlList = [];
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('project');

var regex = '/^'+url+'/';
console.log('regex = '+regex);
collection.find({url: { $regex: regex, $options: 'i' }},function(err,list){

    console.log('length = '+list.length);
    var arrayUrl = [];
    for (var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
        console.log(list[i].url);
        arrayUrl.push(list[i].url);
    }
});
```

But I got list.length = 0 although the database contains the records that match the pattern for sure.

Using the following command on cmd

```
db.project.find({url:{$regex:/^Projek-1/,$options: 'i'}});
```

I got the results I want.

How to use regex on express.js to find matched records in MongoDB database?

Comment: you are passing string instead of regex object. Try using `new RegExp`

Comment: You are using URL string as a regex? You will most likely have to escape it: `var regex = new RegExp("^"+url.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), 'i');`, and remove the `, $options: 'i'` from the later code. Please check.

Comment: I am not sure you see that, but `^` makes the regex match at the beginning of the string only. You will need to remove it if you want to match multiple occurrences of a pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't really need to use `$regex`, you'll do fine with `url: /foobar/i`.

Anyway, the problem is that you are not creating a proper RegExp object, only a string that *looks like* one. Use a proper one by creating a new instance of [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Example:

```
var re = new RegExp("^" + url);

...

find({url: re})
```